# Javascript FileSystemObject::CopyFolder error

Tags: javascript, windows, windows-7, windows-7-x64

I have an old Javascript ..er..script that we run on installs here (with cscript) that stopped working properly somewhere after the beginning of last year. I'm trying to figure out why.

It looks like the CopyFolder method of the FileSystemObject isn't copying over all the files it needs to. *Even if the target directory does not exist*, the copy will fail after copying most of the files with "Permission Denied".

The code is roughly the following:

```
try {
    stat.CopyFolder("C:\myinstalldir\SimulationModule", 
        "C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\\VC\\\VCWizards\\CodeWiz\\Generic\\", true);
} catch (e) {
    WScript.Echo ("CodeWiz Folder copy failed: " + e.message);
}
```

What I'm seeing (again, even if the destination directory doesn't exist), is that all 12 folders get copied over, but only 25 of the 31 files (missing all 5 from one directory, and one from the root directory). The message I see if I run the script manually is: "CodeWiz Folder copy failed: Permission denied"

None of the source files appear to be read-only or hidden, and the same folder copy works just fine if I do it manually via explorer. I'm running as a user in the Admin group. I'm seeing this behavior both on Windows 7 32 and 64 bit.

Any idea what's going on here?